# Rails odd error when submitting collection_select w/ unrelated validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, collection-select

I've got a working form that properly saves all attributes including a `collection_select`. However, when I add `validates :title, presence: true` and try to submit, I get

`undefined method 'map' for nil:NilClass`

My new action:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @item = Item.new
    @categories = Question.editable_by(current_user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :layout => true}
      format.json { render :json => @item  }
      format.js
    end

  end
end
```

View is `items\_form.html.haml`

**Does not work**

`= f.collection_select :question_id, @categories, :_id, :iqs_item`

**Works**

`= f.collection_select :question_id, Question.editable_by(current_user), :_id, :iqs_item`

This works when I add the `@categories` object from the controller to the view. I'm guessing something doesn't get passed for the `error` function in the view or it can't map the select when it tries to redraw the page with errors??

Please assist. Again, I can get it to work, but I'd rather not be putting method calls in the view.

Comment: Can you share the error stacktrace

Comment: I am guessing that `Question.editable_by(current_user)` is returning nil i.e., for current_user there are no editable questions.

Comment: @KirtiThorat, best way to do that is from the `development.log`? And, no, `Question.editable_by(current_user)` consider to be `Question.all`. That function works fine in both controller and view. It's only after submit that it is causing errors.

Comment: Problem is not with function, but with what its returning. Print the value of @categories either in the `controller` or in the `view`. Check if its nil or something else

Comment: Yes you can get it from log file. You could also copy the error trace from the console, where you are running the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`= f.collection_select :question_id, @categories, :_id, :iqs_item`

line would give  `undefined method 'map' for nil:NilClass` error when collection given to it ,i.e., `@categories` is set as `nil`.

Add below mentioned code in the view, if your page displays successfully(without error message) and without a `select` then you know that @categories was set as nil.

```
- unless @categories.nil?
    = f.collection_select :question_id, @categories, :_id, :iqs_item
```

**EDIT**

Also set `@categories` in the create method

Comment: In which view have you added the select drop down? Please share the Controller name and the view name.

Comment: Updated. The view is the normal `new` method with form.